# replace item in a string if it matches an item in the list

Tags: python, list, replace

I am trying to remove words from a string if they match a list.

```
x = "How I Met Your Mother 7x17 (HDTV-LOL) [VTV] - Mon, 20 Feb 2012"

tags = ['HDTV', 'LOL', 'VTV', 'x264', 'DIMENSION', 'XviD', '720P', 'IMMERSE']

print x

for tag in tags:
    if tag in x:
        print x.replace(tag, '')
```

It produces this output:

```
How I Met Your Mother 7x17 (HDTV-LOL) [VTV] - Mon, 20 Feb 2012
How I Met Your Mother 7x17 (-LOL) [VTV] - Mon, 20 Feb 2012
How I Met Your Mother 7x17 (HDTV-) [VTV] - Mon, 20 Feb 2012
How I Met Your Mother 7x17 (HDTV-LOL) [] - Mon, 20 Feb 2012
```

I want it to remove **all** the words matching the list.

Comment: LOL piracy filter love it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are not keeping the result of `x.replace()`. Try the following instead:

```
for tag in tags:
    x = x.replace(tag, '')
print x
```

Note that your approach matches any substring, and not just full words. For example, it would remove the `LOL` in `RUN LOLA RUN`.

One way to address this would be to enclose each tag in a pair of `r'\b'` strings, and look for the resulting [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). The `r'\b'` would only match at word boundaries:

```
for tag in tags:
    x = re.sub(r'\b' + tag + r'\b', '', x)
```

Comment: Thankyou! Any way to remove the brackets "[ ], ( )"? When I add them to list I get an invalid expression error.

Comment: @koogee: I recommend using the original non-regex approach for special characters (`[`, `]`, `(`, `)` and so on).

Comment: Adding '[' ']' to the list gives  `File "test3.py", line 23, in <module>  
    x = re.sub(r'\b' + tag + r'\b', '', x)  
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)  
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile  
    raise error, v # invalid expression  
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression`

Answer (score 7):

The method `str.replace()` does not change the string in place -- strings are immutable in Python.  You have to bind `x` to the new string returned by `replace()` in each iteration:

```
for tag in tags:
    x = x.replace(tag, "")
```

Note that the `if` statement is redundant; `str.replace()` won't do anything if it doesn't find a match.

Answer (score 4):

Using your variables `tags` and `x`, you can use this:

```
output = reduce(lambda a,b: a.replace(b, ''), tags, x)
```

returns:

```
'How I Met Your Mother 7x17 (-) [] - Mon, 20 Feb 2012'
```

Comment: Immutable approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

(1) `x.replace(tag, '')` does not modify `x`, but rather returns a *new* string with the replacement.

(2) why are you printing on each iteration?

The simplest modification you could do would be:

```
for tag in tags:
     x = x.replace(tag, '')
```