# Replace part of string if present in list ( Python )

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I want to replace part of the string to blank if present in a list.

For example :

**List**

```
foo = ['.com', '.net', '.co', '.in']
```

**Convert these strings to**

```
google.com   
google.co.in 
google.net   
google.com/gmail/
```

**These strings**

```
google  
google  
google  
google/gmail/
```

So far i have found this solution. Is there any other optimized way to do it?
[replace item in a string if it matches an item in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396302/replace-item-in-a-string-if-it-matches-an-item-in-the-list)

Comment: why were `'.co'` and `'.in'` appended to the same string?

Comment: And ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis These all are url's https://www.google.co.in/

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396302/replace-item-in-a-string-if-it-matches-an-item-in-the-list I found this solution but i want to know is there any other effective way to do it?

Comment: You should have mentionned this other solution in your question. So, what's wrong with the solution in 9396302 ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers There is nothing wrong in that solution. I only want to know that is there any other optimized way possible ? Because the data that i have is quite large.

Comment: Ok then why didn't you tell all this in your question right from the start , and do you really  need to "optimize" anything  ? I mean: have you tried the other solution on your dataset and is it actually too slow for your needs ? And if yes, how big is your dataset and what are your real constraints ? At some point, the only effective optimization is parallelisation but that's a bit heavy to setup...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to George Shulkin's answer.

```
import re
suffixes = ['.com', '.co', '.in', '.net']
patterns = [re.compile(suffix) for suffix in suffixes]

def remove_suffixes(s: str) -> str:
    for pattern in patterns:
        s = pattern.sub("", s)
    return s

# urls = ["google.com", ...
clean_urls = map(remove_suffixes, urls)
# or clean_urls = [remove_suffixes(url) for url in urls]
```

You might want to use the list comprehension, because it can be faster than `map` in many cases.

This has the advantage of also compiling the regexes, which can be better for performance when used in a loop.

Or if you decided to use `functools.reduce`,

```
from functools import reduce

def remove_suffixes(s: str) -> str:
    return reduce(lambda s, pattern: pattern.sub("", s), patterns, s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` and `str.join`:

```
import re
foo = ['.com', '.net', '.co', '.in']
urls = ["google.com","google.co.in","google.net","google.com/gmail/"]
final_result = [re.sub('|'.join(foo), '', i) for i in urls]
```

Output:

```
['google', 'google', 'google', 'google/gmail/']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this task in two:

1. Write a code to replace string with a new string if matched.
2. Apply this function to the list.

First can be done with regexp (see below). Second can be done by using `map` function.

Example of the code to replace substring:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(".com", "",  "google.com/gmail/")
'google/gmail/'
```

Example for use of the `map` function:

```
>>> map(lambda x: len(x), ["one", "two", "three"])
[3, 3, 5]
```

(it replaces elements of array with length of those elements).

You can combine those two to get what you want.

Comment: Why do you use the lambda in your example when `map(len, ...)` would do?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix I think he wanted to show an example using a lambda function, which might be more useful for the OP. Possibly not the best example here but anyway...

Comment: @Edward Minnix, because I can only phantom a proper partial application in Python. Without it it's hard to see how to use `re.sub` without lambda in `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestion of George Shuklin this is the simplest code i could come up with.

---

```
import re

domains = ['.com', '.net', '.co', '.in']

urls = ["google.com","google.co.in","google.net","google.com/gmail/"]

for i in range(len(urls)):
    for domain in domains:
        urls[i] = re.sub(domain,"",urls[i])

print(urls)
```

---

This outputs:

```
['google', 'google', 'google', 'google/gmail/']
```

Comment: Is it the best way possible. I don't want to go for multiple **for** loops. Is there any pre-built Python function that could do it ?

Comment: @SahilSingla The functions you're looking for are probably `map` and `reduce`, but those can have overhead. I would suggest making a function that loops through replacements, and just use either map or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `str.replace()` and `str.find()`.

```
foo = ['.com', '.net', '.co', '.in']
domains = ["google.com", "google.co.in", "google.net", "google.com/gmail/"]

def remove_extensions(domain, extensions):
    for ext in extensions:
        if domain.find(ext) != -1:
            domain = domain.replace(ext, "")
    return domain

list(map(lambda x: remove_extensions(x, foo), domains))
```

This code snippet outputs the result as expected:

```
['google', 'google', 'google', 'google/gmail/']
```